# HitTestObject Selecting Which One Hit

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been working on this game in actionscript 3 for my class. My game catches fruit into a basket as it falls from the tree and adds a point using the HitTestObject function. When the black fruit called circle hits the basket it is supposed to take a point away. This seems trivial in most other programming languages with an indexed array and a if/else statement. Note sure how to setup a comparison statement with the currentFruit movie clip with  an if/else statement. I thought I would just be able to do something like

```
if(currentFruit.hitTestObject(basket_mc)!=5))
increase fruit
  else
decrease fruit
```

**Here is my code below.**

```
function catchFruit(e:Event):void {

for (var i:int = fruitsOnstage.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
var currentFruit:MovieClip = fruitsOnstage[i];
currentFruit.y += currentFruit.speed;


if (currentFruit.y > stage.stageHeight - currentFruit.
 height) {
currentFruit.y = 0 - currentFruit.height;
fruitsLost++;
field2_txt.text = "Total Fruit Lost: " + fruitsLost;
}


if(currentFruit.hitTestObject(basket_mc)){      
fruitsCollected++;  

field1_txt.text = "Total Fruit Collected: " +
fruitsCollected;


removeChild(currentFruit);
fruitsOnstage.splice(i,1);

}


if (fruitsCollected >= 20) {
basket_mc.gotoAndStop(20);
} else if (fruitsCollected > 15) {
basket_mc.gotoAndStop(15);
} else if (fruitsCollected > 10) {
basket_mc.gotoAndStop(10);
} else if (fruitsCollected > 5) {
basket_mc.gotoAndStop(5);
}

}

if (fruitsOnstage.length <= 0) {
field1_txt.text = "You Win! You have collected enough fruit for dinner.";
field2_txt.text = "";

stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, catchFruit);
}


if (fruitsLost >= 20) {
field1_txt.text = "Sorry, you lose. You have lost too much fruit!";
field2_txt.text = "";

stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, catchFruit);


for (var j:int = fruitsOnstage.length-1; j > -1; j--) {
currentFruit = fruitsOnstage[j];
removeChild(currentFruit);
fruitsOnstage.splice(j,1);
}
}
```

Comment: Your question lacks a question.    What exactly is the issue with your code?  Are you getting an error? an unexpected result?    Quick glance, looks like you are looping inside your loop through the same array which seems odd

Comment: Oh,  looking closer I see your second loop is not inside the first.  You should indent your code properly to make it easier to notice these things. You are missing a closing `}` though at the end of it all.  I don't see anything obviously wrong.  Please provide more details as per my comment above

Answer (score 0):

`hitTestObject()` returns a boolean, so comparing it to an index wouldn't make any sense. You should first check if a collision occurs (with hitTestObject) and then check for the identity of the colliding object.

You can check for the type of the `currentFruit` object after it hits the basket:

```
if(currentFruit.hitTestObject(basket_mc)){
    if(currentFruit is Circle){
        decreaseFruit()
    } else {
        increaseFruit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);
```

This is the complete code and as you can see the black fruit is part of the array with the rest of the fruit that will be falling. This game does work, you catch the fruit and score points, however I want to deduct the point if the black fruit hits the basket. I'm not sure how to determine which fruit hits  the basket. Knowing now it's a boolean result does help just not sure how to set this up.

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
    {

```
var fruitArray:Array = new Array(Apple,Strawberry,Pear,Banana,
 Orange,Circle);
var fruitsOnstage:Array = new Array();
var fruitsCollected:int = 0;
var fruitsLost:int = 0;
for (var i:int = 0; i<20; i++) {
var pickFruit = fruitArray[int(Math.random() * fruitArray.
 length)];
var fruit:MovieClip = new pickFruit();
addChild(fruit);
fruit.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
fruit.y = Math.random() * -500;
fruit.speed = Math.random() * 15 + 5;
fruitsOnstage.push(fruit);
}
basket_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragBasket);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragStop);
function dragBasket(e:Event):void {
basket_mc.startDrag();
}
function dragStop(e:Event):void {


basket_mc.stopDrag();
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, catchFruit);


function catchFruit(e:Event):void {

for (var i:int = fruitsOnstage.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
var currentFruit:MovieClip = fruitsOnstage[i];
currentFruit.y += currentFruit.speed;


if (currentFruit.y > stage.stageHeight - currentFruit.
 height) {
currentFruit.y = 0 - currentFruit.height;
fruitsLost++;
field2_txt.text = "Total Fruit Lost: " + fruitsLost;
}


if(currentFruit.hitTestObject(basket_mc)){      
fruitsCollected++;  

field1_txt.text = "Total Fruit Collected: " +
fruitsCollected;


removeChild(currentFruit);
fruitsOnstage.splice(i,1);

}


if (fruitsCollected >= 20) {
basket_mc.gotoAndStop(20);
} else if (fruitsCollected > 15) {
basket_mc.gotoAndStop(15);
} else if (fruitsCollected > 10) {
basket_mc.gotoAndStop(10);
} else if (fruitsCollected > 5) {
basket_mc.gotoAndStop(5);
}

}

if (fruitsOnstage.length <= 0) {
field1_txt.text = "You Win! You have collected enough fruit for dinner.";
field2_txt.text = "";

stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, catchFruit);
}


if (fruitsLost >= 20) {
field1_txt.text = "Sorry, you lose. You have lost too much fruit!";
field2_txt.text = "";

stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, catchFruit);


for (var j:int = fruitsOnstage.length-1; j > -1; j--) {
currentFruit = fruitsOnstage[j];
removeChild(currentFruit);
fruitsOnstage.splice(j,1);
}
}






}

}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to check if the colliding object is of type `Circle`.